# PowerShell delayed output

Tags: powershell

I have had this trouble with multiple scripts I've written and I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but I'll have something like:

```
#What Server
$Server = Read-Host "Enter the name of the target server: "

#Get initial volume info
$IDisk = invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{Get-volume}
$IDisk

#Ask which disk to expand
$WhatDisk = Read-Host "Which disk would you like to expand: "

#Update the disk info
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{Update-HostStorageCache}

#Display before and after for the target drive
Write-Host "Disk $WhatDisk is currently: " -ForeGroundColor "Cyan"
$IDisk | Select DriveLetter, FileSystemLabel, @{Name='Size(GB)';Exp={$_.Size /1gb -as [int]}} | Where {$_.DriveLetter -eq $WhatDisk}
```

The script doesn't output the info from $IDisk AFTER the next output. As in:

```
Enter the name of the target server: : server443

Which disk would you like to expand: : l
Disk l is currently:
DriveLetter FriendlyName          FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining     Size 
----------- ------------          -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------     ---- 
E           (V2)                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     12.75 GB 24.98 GB 
L           (V3)                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      1.89 GB  1.98 GB 
U           (V5)                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      2.04 GB  4.98 GB 
P           (V4)                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     18.99 GB 19.98 GB 
Z           (V6)                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                      4.06 GB  4.98 GB 
B                                 Unknown        CD-ROM    Healthy      Unknown                     0 B      0 B 
            System Reserved       NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     67.12 MB   100 MB 
C                                 NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     32.12 GB 79.33 GB 
                                  NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                    114.61 MB   578 MB 

DriveLetter     : L
FileSystemLabel : (V3)
Size(GB)        : 2
```

Does anyone know why the output from $IDisk is held from being output until the next output is called, in this case the second call of $IDisk? And how can I stop this from happening?

Again, this is just an example, but I have had a lot of trouble with this.

Comment: I suspect this is because you use invoke-command to send the command to the remote side, and the script continues before receiving all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table-formatted indirect console output like your `$IDisk` is slightly asynchronous in Powershell, and can sometimes show up out of order in the console window when mixing with other output.

To fix, you can force powershell to do the formatting beforehand by piping your output to `Out-Host` or `Format-Table` like:

```sh
#Get initial volume info
$IDisk = invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{Get-volume}
$IDisk | Out-Host

#Ask which disk to expand
$WhatDisk = Read-Host "Which disk would you like to expand: "
```

There is an exhaustive explanation of this behavior over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43691123/7411885